# drupal 7 filter nodes by 2 taxonomyes

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I have one content type Society and 2 taxonomy type: product and country. my content have 1 field for each taxonomy. Now i have to create a view with exposed filters for that content type, filtering by taxonomy
so i will have a block with 2 dropdown 
1. Country
2. Product
My problem now: first dropdown will return not all taxonomy terms, but only the ones that have a node, and the second should give me the product for the society of first dropdown.... 
example

1 country: A, B, C
2 product : P1, P2, P3
Society 1 : country A
                 Product P2 P3
Society 2 : country B
                 product P1 P3
on block i will have :
first drop Down: country A B
second drop Down if I select country A product P2 P3
and i see the society that are in that country with that products

I can't make one vocaboulary for all, products are 3 society are many and hierarchy structured

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Tried many but without results.... i have to create a module with sql call?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with some SQL and Javascript:

1. In your module write a query selecting all countries which are assigned to nodes of type Society joined (INNER JOIN) with all products for these nodes.
2. Add the results as a Drupal setting (with **drupal_add_js(array('my_module'$ => data), 'setting')**). The $data variable should be an associative array with cities as keys and the product for each city (from the query results) as  values.
3. In the Javascript fill the first drop down with all keys (Countries) from the variable in **Drupal.settings** and the second drop-down with all the values (Products).
4. Make an event which populates the product drop-down when changing the value of the county drop-down.